# Sqlite: LIKE matches value, but equality doesn't

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have very simple SQLite table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `settings` (`Name` TEXT PRIMARY KEY, `Value` TEXT);
```

I use 2 following queries:

```
SELECT `Value` FROM `settings` WHERE `Name` LIKE 'MainTabControl.active';
```

(returns 1 row)

and

```
SELECT `Value` FROM `settings` WHERE `Name` = 'MainTabControl.active';
```

(returns 0 rows)

Row with `Name` column value `MainTabControl.active` definitely exists (I see it when do `SELECT *`), doesn't have any spaces at beginning and end, and has the same case of all characters.
What is reason of different behavior of equality operator and `LIKE`?

Comment: @gordon: sqlite, not mysql

Comment: Hi, no, as I am writing directly in my question, no spaces at the end and begin, I use SQLite C++ API to get data with SELECT *, and all data is without spaces.

Comment: Which version of sqlite are you using? I just tested it with 3.7.13 on my system with the `sqlite3`-cli and it works.

Comment: are you sure there's no unprintable characters in there? e.g. maybe a line feed? what does a `length(Name)` show for that particular field?

Comment: My SQLite version: #define SQLITE_VERSION "3.7.14.1" When I do SELECT `Name`, `Value`, length(`Name`) FROM `settings` it returns MainTabControl.active, 3, 21. It worked for me in past, but it stopped when I started to use queries on this DB with "COLLATE NOCASE like that: SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `col` LIKE '%' || a || '%' COLLATE NOCASE; but it is on another table for this database. May COLLATE used in "where" on another table somehow affect `settings` table?

Answer (score 4):

You may be running into sqlite's type system.  Full details are on http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html, but the relevant bit is this:

```
A TEXT value is less than a BLOB value
```

My guess is that you (intentionally or not) stored the name column as a BLOB rather than TEXT.  This will not be `=` to the text value, but will be `LIKE` it.

```
$ sqlite3
SQLite version 3.7.15 2012-10-15 18:02:57
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> create table settings (name, value) ;
sqlite> insert into settings values ('MainTabControl.active','textname') ;
sqlite> insert into settings values (cast ('MainTabControl.active' as blob),'blobname') ;
sqlite> select value from settings where name = 'MainTabControl.active' ;
textname
sqlite> select value from settings where name like 'MainTabControl.active' ;
textname
blobname
sqlite> select value, typeof(name) from settings where name like 'MainTabControl.active' ;
textname|text
blobname|blob
sqlite>
```

Answer (score 1):

The case sensitivity of the LIKE operator is determined
by the PRAGMA case_sensitive_like command. 
The default behavior of the LIKE operator is to ignore case for 
ASCII characters.

```
sqlite> SELECT 'A' = 'a';
0         
sqlite> SELECT 'A' LIKE 'a';
1           
sqlite> PRAGMA case_sensitive_like = TRUE;
sqlite> SELECT 'A' LIKE 'a';
0
```

If we set it to TRUE, the result is equal to the = operator.
see http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_case_sensitive_like

Comment: PRAGMA case_sensitive_like = TRUE doesn't change anything in my situation; LIKE still returns 1 row, = returns 0 ones.

Comment: Could you post the output of the .dump settings command?
(.output setting.sql will redirect the output to a file)
It might have some useful information of how the value is
exactly stored.

Comment: It looks like I experience any bug in SQLite. I continued tests with the same database, on other table I started to receive SQLITE_INTERNAL errors on prepare_v2 calls to very simple queries that can not be wrong (like SELECT * FROM `table`). From the other hand, PRAGMA integrity_check gives OK. I even exported data with .dump and imported it in empty database, but result is the same. SQLITE_INTERNAL means bug in SQLite according to theirs documentation.