# sqlite why select like works and equals does not?

Tags: database, sqlite

I have a problem with sqlite3 database, I execute the following queries

> sqlite> select * from property where link like
>   "http://www.domain.com/huur/den-bosch/appartement-48118689-meester-spoermekerlaan-88/";

I get two rows

> 17|2014-11-03|Meester Spoermekerlaan
>   88|http://www.domain.com/huur/den-bosch/appartement-48118689-meester-spoermekerlaan-88/|5237
>   JZ|Den Bosch|€ 789|3|1
>
> 32|2014-11-03|Meester Spoermekerlaan
>   88|http://www.domain.com/huur/den-bosch/appartement-48118689-meester-spoermekerlaan-88/|5237
>   JZ|Den Bosch|€ 789|3|1

Then I execute the same query, but using the equality operator, like so

> sqlite> select * from property where
>   link="http://www.domain.com/huur/den-bosch/appartement-48118689-meester-spoermekerlaan-88/";
>
> sqlite> (<---- no results??)

I already found a similar answer to mine, however the issue is not the same, my fields are of datatype "text", as you can see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14823565/279147

> sqlite> .schema property
>
> CREATE TABLE property (id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,"date" text,address text,link text,postcode text,city text,price text,rooms text,page integer);

So does anybody have any idea why this would happen? here is my version information

> root@s1:/# sqlite3 application.sqlite3
>
> SQLite version 3.7.3

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT DISTINCT typeof(link) FROM property;`?

Comment: thats weird.....it says "blob" which then correlates with what was said in the other question....but the .schema property says "link text" so why the difference of opinion between those two? shouldn't they be the same? or perhaps it's sqlite3 doing some optimisation?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.  This work around worked for me.

SELECT * from foo WHERE CAST(name AS BLOB) = CAST('bla' AS BLOB);

Comment: This solved a situation in a PHP project where I'd forgotten the datatype, ie `bindValue(..., ..., SQLITE3_BLOB);`.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite uses [dynamic typing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html); it does not matter if the `link` column is declared as `text` or `blob` or `fluffy bunnies`.

LIKE automatically converts its parameters into strings, but the `=` operator does not.

Fix the program that writes the entries to the database to use the correct data type.

Comment: this is the link which binds that field, maybe I understood this bindValue method? "$query->bindValue(":link", $item["link"], SQLITE3_TEXT);" I understood SQLITE3_TEXT to write a text type....

Comment: The original question has been answered. Ask a new question.

Comment: not in my opinion, I'm asking for a SQLITE3_TEXT data type and according to an above comment, it's appearing as a blob, so this is still a mystery.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a forum but a Q&A site. The question you actually asked is about the different behaviour of LIKE and =.

Comment: your answer is not sufficiently answering the question, maybe somebody else can read the extra information and give a more complete answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue, in my case the point was, the like is not case sensitive, but the `=` operator is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `=` is a literal string comparison so it would have to be exactly the same.
The `like` operator is looking for a matching pattern within the string and finds it.

Comment: I think the OP is aware of that. The question is why the observed behavior is occurring when the strings in question appear to be identical.

Comment: Oh yeah, my mistake, I misread the |5237 as being a part of the link for some reason. Thought it was odd, lol.