# SQLite - Mixed BLOBS and TEXTS

Tags: sqlite

Before knowing that SQLite uses [dynamic typing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) I somehow end up storing blobs as texts creating the "[like works, equals don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26719948/sqlite-why-select-like-works-and-equals-does-not)" as described in this question. So I have a TEXTs and BLOBs mixed all over the place, making queries like:

`select * from a where FIELD in (select b.FIELD2 from b where b.FIELD2 = 'bla')`

Stop working properly.

Now that I now this dynamic typing thing, I'll be more carefully when storing to the DB. But I need to turn all my data into TEXT again.

So my question is:

**How do I turn all my blobs cells into text cells?**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check the type of a value, use the [typeof() function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#typeof):

```
UPDATE b
SET Field2 = CAST(Field2 AS TEXT)
WHERE typeof(Field2) = 'blob';
```